# Passing value to function in somearray.map on button click but its not pass the vlaue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, onclick

I'm facing an issue, when I click on the update or delete button it's not passing any value to the function. Please help me out. On **update** is clicked, it should pass `val.movie_name` to `updatereview` function. Similarly when **delete** is clicked, it should pass the `val.movie_name` to `deletemoviereview` function.

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import { Container,Row,Col,Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
import Axios from 'axios';

function App() {

  const [movieName, setMovieName] = useState("");
  const [review, setrReview] = useState("");
  const [movielist,setmovielist]=useState([]);
  const [newreview,setnewreview]=useState("");


useEffect(()=>{
  Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/get').then((response)=>{
    setmovielist(response.data); 
  } )
})

  const submitReview=()=>{
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/insert",{movieName:movieName,movieReview:review});
    
    setmovielist([movielist,{movieName:movieName,movieReview:review}]);
    setMovieName("");
    setrReview("");
  };

// issue is that deletemoviereview is not receiving any value on  Click Delete button
  const deletemoviereview=(movie)=>{
    Axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/api/delete/${movie}`)
  }

//issue is that below "updatereview" function is not receiving any value on the update button click

  const updatereview=(movie)=>{
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/update",{
      movieName:movie,
      movieReview:newreview,
    });
    setmovielist("");
  };


  return (
    <div className="App">
    <Container>
      <Row>
          <Col sm={12}>
            <h1 className="appheading">Curd Application</h1>
            <div className="form">
               <label>Movie Name</label>
               <input 
                type="text" 
                name="movieName" 
                onChange={(e)=>{
                setMovieName(e.target.value);
               }}/>
               <label>Review</label>
               <input 
                type="text" 
                name="review" 
                onChange={(e)=>{
                 setrReview(e.target.value);
               }}/>
               <button onClick={submitReview}>Save</button>
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
         {movielist.map((val)=>{
          return (
           <Col md={3}>
            <div className="moviecard">
                <h3 className="card-heading">{val.movie_name}</h3>
                <p className="card--review">{val.moview_review}</p>
                <div className="buttons">
                <Button variant="danger" onclick={()=>{deletemoviereview(val.movie_name)}}>Delete</Button>
                <input type="text" id="updateinput" onChange={(e)=>{setnewreview(e.target.value)}}></input>
                <Button onclick={()=> {updatereview(val.movie_name)}}>Update</Button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </Col>
           );
          })}
       </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I guess you val.movie_name is displaying something in the jsx and you tried to console.log(movie) in your functions, does it appear as undefined?

Comment: jimmy , as "movielist.map((val)" id used and val.movie_name has movie name which is first column/value on  movielist

Comment: when tried by console.log(movie) . nothing in console

Answer (score 1):

You should change `onclick` events to `onClick` in both your **Update** and **Delete** buttons because [React events are named using camelCase, rather than lowercase](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).